# What does "break when an exception is void" mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, exception

I have found the automatic break-on-exception feature of Visual C++ 2010 to be very helpful in the past and today I was looking through the options in this dialog and discovered that one of the exception types is "void". What does this mean? If I select this, will I break on any exception that is thrown in the code? If not, what kind of a throw statement would trigger a breakpoint of this type?

[image: Visual Studio Exceptions Dialog]

I suppose a more general follow-up question is where can I find documentation on this dialog and all its options?

Comment: My first bet would have been: it's meant as a proxy for any type not derived from any of the other exceptions (including `throw 5;`). A short test reveals: that's not the case - looking forward to the answer...

Comment: Just curious: did you manage to get it to catch a "void" exception in the debugger?

Comment: @doug65536 Well, interestingly, if I used a void* I was about to get it to work, but that doesn't seem like the use it was intended for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding on how does it work (as MSalters mentioned) this is just about incorrect naming.

Actually it shall be named **`void*`**, of course.

But why does it work for `int*`, `const char*` etc (actually **any pointer type**, including pointer to user defined types)?

Well, I can suppose this is related to very interesting C++ exception handling issue - `catch(void*)` exception handler **actually catches any (cv-compatible) pointer type exceptions**!

Example:

```
try
{
   throw "Catch me if you can!";      
}
catch(void* e)
{
   // ...and I can!
   std::cout << "Gotcha!" << std::endl;
}
```

Here we throw `char*` (in Visual C++ char literals are `char*`, not `const char*`) and catch it by `void*`. And it will work!

The answer can be found in C++ Holy Standard:

> **§15.3 Handling an exception**
>
> 15.3.3 A handler is a match for an exception object of type E if
>
> ...
>
> the handler is of type cv1 T* cv2 and E is a pointer type that can be converted to the type of the handler by either or both of
>   — a standard pointer conversion (4.10) not involving conversions to pointers to private or protected or ambiguous classes
>
> ...

And 4.10 says that standard pointer conversion includes conversion to `void*`:

> 4.10.2 A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T,” where T is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
>   to cv void”.

Note also that Visual Studio debugger works similar way, but *not exactly* this way. The difference is that it ignores cv-qualifiers. So `void` in Exceptions dialog actually means any `[any cv] void*`. Catch handlers will **not ignore** them:

```
try
{
   struct Throwee {};
   const Throwee* t = nullptr;
   throw t;      
}
catch(void* e)
{
   // Will be missed
   std::cout << "Gotcha!" << std::endl;
}
catch(const void* e)
{
   // Will be catched
   std::cout << "Gotcha const!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. This is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've found that it will break when throwing a `void*`, `int*` or `char const*`, but not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that's the setting for catch (...). Either that propagated `throw;` statements.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. A simple test confirmed it was not the case for me.

Comment: And a `throw;` outside of a catch block causes an unhandled exception which isn't caught by `catch(...)` since it's a structured exception.